# How to install themes in magento 2.0 without using magento connect manager?

Tags: magento2, theme

I'm new to Magento 2.0. I'm not able to install themes in it, because in magento 2.0 version there is no magento connect manager. Can anyone tell me the exact way to install themes without using magento connect manager.

Answer (score 4):

> To install the theme in magento 2 manually you must need to know
>   directory structure of magento2.

- like for design you need to put files in app/design folder
- like for modules you need to put files in app/code folder
- also for sql file you need to import that sql file in your database
- For images you need to put your images file in pub/media folder

For more reference use this link - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39995942/installing-magento2-theme

Answer (score 0):

upload it via ftp. please check the docs from http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-general.html

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply... Can u please upload the step by step process of how to upload the theme zip file, and also magento connect theme

Comment: I upload the theme's zip folders in app and skin. but i dono how to access it in magneto 2.0.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if or how uploading a zip works, but you can always extract the zip file on your local machine and then use ftp to move the contents, the root folder (the one with the theme.xml) is located at:
app/design/[frontend|backend]/[vendor]/[name]

Answer (score 0):

First, upload your theme unzip folder to the root directory of your Magento 2 store.

Connect your store with SSH and run these commands in the root directory

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Then go to **CONTENT → Configuration** from the admin panel of your store to activate your theme.